# Global stochastic maximization of a multi-parameter function

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, machine-learning, stochastic-approximation

I have a function $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to[0,1]$ such that
$$ F(\lambda) =  \mathbb{E}_x[f(\lambda;x)] = \int f(\lambda;x)\mu(x)dx,$$
and I want to find $\tilde\lambda$ that maximizes F, i.e. $F(\tilde\lambda)=1$. Clearly, $\tilde\lambda$ is not unique. What is the best algorithm to find one of the $\tilde\lambda$?

For the moment I tried the stochastic gradient descent (with a random guess of $\tilde\lambda$ and with a discretization of $\mu(x)$) with moderate success when $n$ is small $\simeq 7$. I went for stochastic gradient descent for its ability to escape some local minima. What is the optimal algorithm when $n\simeq20$?

Notes:

- I can also evaluate the expectation value analytically, so my problem can be cast into a global optimization problem without any random part. Is there any advantage in exploiting the stochastic nature of my function? To the best of my knowledge, most global optimization algorithms have some stochastic part.
- I already know the maximum value (1), so in some sense my question is also a root-finding problem.
- I don't know the gradient of $F$, nor the gradient of $f$. However $F$ and $f$ are smooth.

Comment: I don't see the stochastic nature of your problem. You are trying to maximize an expected value, which is deterministic. Why don't you just differentiate the integral with respect to $\lambda$ and see if you can move the derivative inside the integral?

Comment: @Calculon benkj is right that often global optimization algorithms even for deterministic functions use some stochastic element to escape local extrema. It seems that the question is: is it much harder to directly maximize $F$ than it is to maximize $f(\lambda;x)$ for fixed sampled values of $x$?

Comment: @Ian do you mean the stochastic gradient descent part of benkj's post?

Comment: @Calculon I was referring to the last sentence of the first bullet.

Comment: @Ian Yeah but that is about the algorithm that solves some problem. In the same bullet point benkj is talking about the stochastic nature of the problem itself. I am assuming here he/she is referring to the fact there is an expected value involved in the problem. My comment about the absence of stochastic nature was related to this.

Comment: @Calculon Sure, benkj is optimizing a deterministic function. But the question is about algorithms, not analytic optimization.

Comment: @Ian "Is there any advantages in exploiting the stochastic nature of my function?" I was simply trying to explain that the function in question has no stochastic nature. I also got the impression that benkj was led to this stochastic gradient descent algorithm because he thought there was something stochastic about the optimization problem itself. I may be wrong about that part.

Comment: @Calculon what I meant is exactly what Ian said. I can use directly a global optimization algorithm on F, which typically adds some stochastic part. I was wondering if I can exploit the fact that F is an expectation value to add some randomness in the problem, and if there are any advantages in doing this. With some numerical tests, it seems that the stochastic gradient descent is better than the global search for intermediate values of n (e.g. n=10)

Comment: It seems like it would depend a lot on the character of $\mu$. For example if $\mu$ is relatively concentrated then sampling would give a lot of information about it.